# Soundcloud HTML5 Volume Control

Tags: volume, soundcloud

I have a track on my website which utilizes the soundcloud HTML5 player. I was wondering if there is any way I can make it a little quieter that way it doesn't shock the viewer upon opening my page. If anyone could lead me in the right direction as to how to alter the players volume on soundcloud it would be much appreciated :D

I know it has something to do with javascript: `setVolume(volume)` but I'm not familiar with JavaScript so if someone could help me out that'd be great. I want the volume to be at 50%.

If need be, i could also use the flash player.

I'm fine with using either HTML5 or flash player, I just want the volume to be set at 50% when someone plays it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the [Widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget#)

Basically, the widget is embedded into your page with an iframe. Give the iframe an `id`, include the API library (linked above) and then it's really simple.

```
SC.Widget('myIframeId').setVolume(50);
```

Comment: im so terrible at javascript is there any way you could show me an example?

Comment: could you please help me out? if you could message me the code i would be very thankful

Comment: Yes, include that script on your page and then run the code in the answer above (replacing `'myIframeId'` with the id that you give to the iframe)